# How to run emulator from command line

Tags: android, ionic4

```
emulator: ERROR: No AVD specified. Use '@foo' or '-avd foo' to launch a virtual device named 'fo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you did not specify the correct name of your AVD. You can use `emulator -list-avds` to see a list of your available AVDs and use their name with `emulator -avd {name_of_avd}` to run that AVD. For more information check [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline)

Comment: i just copied avd name from the list.

Comment: Thank you it was an issue of android studio.